# Externalization of tikz/pgfplots graphics included by tikzscale package with hyperref cross references

Tags: pgfplots, hyperref, cross-referencing, tikz-external, tikzscale

As the long title says, I'd like to include the following aspects in my `LaTeX` project.

- `external` library of `TikZ` to externalize possibly infinite compilation times due to both plane `TikZ` and huge `PGFplots` figures;
- `\tikzsetnextfilename` before each `tikzpicure` to avoid recompiling figures when changing the order they appear in the document;
- `tikzscale` package to allow using `\includegraphics` with provided `width` and `.tikz` input file;
- `hyperref` package for obvious reasons;
- `\ref` in `tikzpicure` referencing a `\label` in the main text;
- `\ref` in the main text referencing a `\label` in a `tikzpicture` (in particular referencing an `\addplot`);

Before checking how to make `hyperref` and `TikZexternal` work together (I
see there are a lot of Q&A already), I'd like to understand what's wrong with the following sample project.

I've read the concerned section in both manuals (`TikZ` and `PGFplots`) and I think I understood most of it, but maybe I'm wrong...

The use of `mode=list and make` seems to be necessary to deal with my "requests" [it forces me to run manually a makefile, which I hate to do since it slows me down a lot; on the other hand I should be able, sooner or later, to solve this problem separately with `VimTeX`].

What I do to have the result with **one** of the two figures is compiling the `tex` file, running the `.makefile` automatically produced, and then rerun pdflatex.

The problem is that when the two figures are inclueded, the references I put in the two captions are wrong. Indeed, I see that `*crossref*.pdf` files numbered from 3 to 5 are exactly the same as those form 0 to 2.

In addition, I get a warning about multiply defined label for each one of the six labels.

Main file:

```
\documentclass{article}

%\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikzscale}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.14}
\usetikzlibrary{external, pgfplots.groupplots}
%\usepackage{hyperref}

\tikzexternalize[mode=list and make]

\begin{document}

\section{zero}
\label{sec:zero}
Hello!
\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \tikzsetnextfilename{figura1}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{fig1.tikz}
    \caption{This is stupid figure.\ref{pgf:first} \ref{pgf:second} \ref{pgf:third}}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\section{First}
\label{sec:first}
Hello!

\begin{figure}[h]
    \centering
    \tikzsetnextfilename{figura2}
    \includegraphics[width=.5\textwidth]{fig2.tikz}
    \caption{This is stupid figure.\ref{pgf:fourth} \ref{pgf:fifth} \ref{pgf:sixth}}
    \label{fig:fig1}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

First TikZ file (`fig1.tikz`)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{groupplot}[group style={group size=2 by 2},height=3cm,width=3cm]
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[blue] coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};\addlegendentry{first}
        \label{pgf:first}
        \addplot[red] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};\addlegendentry{second}
        \label{pgf:second}
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[black] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};\addlegendentry{third, from sec. \ref{sec:first}}
        \label{pgf:third}
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[black, mark=*] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,1)};
        \nextgroupplot
        \addplot[black, mark=*] coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (1,0)};
    \end{groupplot}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Second TikZ file (`fig2.tikz`)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}
        \addplot+ coordinates {(0,0) (1,1) (2,2)};\addlegendentry{first}
        \label{pgf:fourth}
        \addplot+ coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};\addlegendentry{second}
        \label{pgf:fifth}
        \addplot+ coordinates {(0,2) (1,1) (2,0)};\addlegendentry{third, from sec. \ref{sec:zero}}
        \label{pgf:sixth}
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Comment: in .main: `\label{fig:fig1}` is used multiple times. So change one label for example to `\label{fig:fig2}`.

Comment: Corrected, it was a typo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that the cross-references fail to work inside of `\caption`. The root cause appears to be that `\caption` is typeset twice, but I'll have to understand why before I can address it.

I will file a ticket to look into into eventually.

A workaround for you is to replace

```
\tikzsetnextfilename{figura2}
```

by

```
\tikzset{external/figure name=figura2_}
```

The difference is that the first command affects only the figure as such (in this case, the figure in `fig2.tikz` whereas the second command affects *all* following figures in scope -- in particular, it also defines unique names for the cross referenced minipictures.

The approach results in *6* crossref pictures for each `\caption` and I do not know why or how to suppress it. I suppose that the `figure` environment somehow processes `\caption` twice for unknown reasons (scaling? alignment?).